# How to store a string (line) in an AWK variable

Tags: awk

Writing an AWK script, I want to store a line I find in a variable, and only later, if I also match another line, print out that original line.

Example:

```
a    <-- save this one
b
c    <-- Now that we found c, let's print a
```

Psudo, wish-it-worked-exactly-like-this, code:

```
/a/ { myvar = $0 }
/c/ { print $myvar $0 }
```

In dreamland produces:

```
ac
```

Actual, psychedelic, results of my wishful-thinking psudo code:

```
cc
```

Note: it's cheating to answer "just print `a`, then `c` as would work with a simplification of this example. The real-world use case calls for `c` only being printed based on further conditions, thus the need to store the most recently seen `a` on the *chance* a following `c` will be printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

working code

```
/a/ { myvar = $0 }
/c/ { print myvar $0 }
```

Think of `$` as an **operator**, that fetches the value of the given 
field number.

Here `myvar` holds the value "a". A string that does not begin with digits is considered to have the value zero, when taken in a numeric context. Thus, `$myvar` is seen as `$"a"` which is `$0`

A strange way to take advantage of this:

```
awk '/a/ {myvar = $0} /c/ {print $myvar $1}' <<END
2a
b
c d
END
```

will output

```
dc
```

Comment: +1 another common way to think of `$` is as the name of an array of fields. It kinda falls apart syntactically but functionally it's not a bad analogy.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dollar sign in front of `myvar`